# press TouchableOpacity DO NOT switch to another page

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is an example in my code which can switch to another page when you press. 
this is the first part:

```
_onPress(projno){
    if(currentIndex == this.index){
      this.navigator.push({
        component:TeamDetailPage,
        passProps:{projno:projno}
      })
    } else {
      return;
    }
    }
```

this is the second part:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styleRow.item2} delayLongPress={300} onPress={() => this._onPress(this.props.projno)}>
<Image style={{width:30,height:30}}source={HomeRankViewImgs[7]}/>
<Text style={styleRow.teamName}>{this.shotna}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I refer to the successful one and write the following code,but it did not work:
 this is the first part:

```
 _onPress(projno){
    if(currentIndex == this.index){
      this.navigator.push({
        component:TeamDetailPage,
        passProps:{projno:projno}
      })
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

this is the second part:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styleRow.item2} delayLongPress={300} onPress={() => this._onPress(this.props.projno)}>
    <View style={teamInfoViewStyles.leftWrap}>
      <Image style={teamInfoViewStyles.teamImg}
        source={this.props.imgpath} />
      <View style={teamInfoViewStyles.infoWrap}>
        <Text style={teamInfoViewStyles.teamName}>
          {this.props.teamName}
        </Text>
        <Text style={teamInfoViewStyles.teamRank}>
          {this.props.rank}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is not clear. Which part of this code is not working and which part is?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding "this" while calling _onPress():

onPress={this._onPress(this.props.projno).bind(this)}